# Fps of AVPlayer on macOS in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, avplayer, frame-rate

I see this on iOS posts, but can't get it to work on macOS:

```
self.player?.currentItem?.asset.nominalFrameRate
```

I get this eror:

```
Value of type 'AVAsset' has no member 'nominalFrameRate'
```

Dose anyone know how to get the fps of the AVPlayer or a movie file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16117255/6846532

Comment: Thanks @VasiliiMuravev!