# How to sync AVPlayer and MTKView

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, avplayer, metal

I have a project where users can take a video and later add filters to them or change basic settings like brightness and contrast. To accomplish this, I use [BBMetalImage](https://github.com/Silence-GitHub/BBMetalImage), which basically returns the video in a MTKView (named a `BBMetalView` in the project).

Everything works great - I can play the video, add filters and the desired effects, but there is no audio. I [asked the author](https://github.com/Silence-GitHub/BBMetalImage/issues/19) about this, who recommended using an `AVPlayer` (or `AVAudioPlayer`) for this. So I did. However, the video and audio are out of sync. Possibly because of different bitrates in the first place, and the author of the library also mentioned the frame rate can differ because of the filter process (the time this consumes is variable):

> The render view FPS is not exactly the same to the actual rate.
>   Because the video source output frame is processed by filters and the
>   filter process time is variable.

First, I crop my video to the desired aspect ratio (4:5). I save this file (480x600) locally, using `AVVideoProfileLevelH264HighAutoLevel` as `AVVideoProfileLevelKey`. My audio configuration, using [NextLevelSessionExporter](https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevelSessionExporter), has the following setup: `AVEncoderBitRateKey: 128000`, `AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2`, `AVSampleRateKey: 44100`.

Then, the BBMetalImage library takes this saved audio file and provides a MTKView (BBMetalView) to display the video, allowing me to add filters and effects in real time. The setup kind of looks like this:

```
self.metalView = BBMetalView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.center.y - ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.25) / 2), width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.25))
self.view.addSubview(self.metalView)
self.videoSource = BBMetalVideoSource(url: outputURL)
self.videoSource.playWithVideoRate = true
self.videoSource.audioConsumer = self.metalAudio
self.videoSource.add(consumer: self.metalView)
self.videoSource.add(consumer: self.videoWriter)
self.audioItem = AVPlayerItem(url: outputURL)                            
self.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.audioItem)
self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.audioPlayer)
self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
self.playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
self.playerLayer?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.startVideo()
```

And `startVideo()` goes like this:

```
audioPlayer.seek(to: .zero)
audioPlayer.play()
videoSource.start(progress: { (frameTime) in
    print(frameTime)
}) { [weak self] (finish) in
guard let self = self else { return }
    self.startVideo()
}
```

This is all probably pretty vague because of the external library/libraries. However, my question is pretty simple: is there any way I can sync the `MTKView` with my `AVPlayer`? It would help me a lot and I'm sure `Silence-GitHub` would also implement this feature into the library to help a lot of other users. Any ideas on how to approach this are welcome!

Comment: So, to give you some insight -- audio is usually not recorded at a `frameRate` per say, whereas video definitely has a `frameRate`. The trick to this is that the `MTKView` may or may not have some issues, which COULD affect the `frameRate`. For example, let's say that for some reason the `MTKView` is being updated every 15fps, we don't want our audio to be recorded every 15fps. We want audio to come in for every "millisecond" per say. So, the simple lay out should be `Thread 1 - record Video to the best of your ability` and `Thread 2 - record Audio so it has no issues waiting for MTKView`.

Comment: I deleted my previous 2nd comment, as I more thoroughly understand your question. So, you are recording a video and the video contains the video and audio but when you play them, they are out of sync. I see. Can you print out `asset.tracksWithMediaType(.audio)[0].timeRange` as well as using `.video` and see if your audio and video tracks have the same length?

Comment: Ah, no. Maybe I didn’t make my flow that clear. I record and save a video file in my temporary directory - which has the right video and audio track. Those are exported using NextLevelSessionExporter, and when I save this to my camera roll, it all plays well and in sync. The issue occurs, however, in the next part. I take this raw video file and render it through a MetalView, because now, with this recorded video, I want to allow users to add filters and effects. So I play the videoframes through this MetalView and I currently have an AVPlayer to play the audio, in my app.

Comment: So I feel like I can only get the tracksWithMediaType(.audio) because the video is not shown through an AVAsset, but through this MTKView (BBMetalView).

Comment: Ok, understanding more. So, when you play it normal, say through the camera roll, all is well. However, when you separate the 2, and attempt to use a custom MTKView for video and a separate AVPlayer for audio, it causes this disjunction. Is there a specific pattern? Is the video always faster/slower than the audio?

Comment: Better question - when you print frameTime - what are some examples you are getting? I’d prefer to know from more than 1 source. Say 3.

Comment: I ask this because if the video is being played back at a random rate - say each frame is being processed at 60 fps with the applied filter, then the audio can be played back normally (probably). However, imagine if the filtering is causing the MTKView to be processed at 1 fps but you want to play audio. Do you know what audio would sound like if a video was played at 1 fps? I don't want to know either. So, it depends if you are trying to slow/speed up the audio or attempt to speed up the filtering.

Comment: Audio plays back at normal speed. The AVPlayer is not changd in any way, I start the AVPlayer when I start rendering the MTKView (however, the sound starts a little sooner, probably because it takes some time to initialize the MTKView). The frames are delayed, caused by the filtering process, so yeah, video frames are pretty much unpredictable when they are rendered. I’ll post a pastebin with a couple of examples of the frameTime from audio and video (when I save the video, not when it’s playing in my app, but when I hit the OK button and it starts writing to a new mp4 file). Just a sec.

Comment: Please take a look at https://pastebin.com/0v0VDSjU. I do see some kind of pattern, where the video frames have a timescale of 600, while audio has a timescale of 44100. This matches my output of the NextLevelSessionExporter, I save the mp4 file to my temporary file using an AVVideoAverageBitRateKey of 6000000 and an AVSampleRateKey of 44100. This looks promising, right? - This is, however, when I SAVE the video to an mp4 file. This is NOT the output of the MTKView. How can I access these values? Can I show the frame rate of the MTKView?

Comment: Another output, from the videoSource which renders in the MTKView (the metalView is a consumer of the videoSource, so it's probably not the real frame rate of the MTKView. Can't figure out how I can access this): https://pastebin.com/vvaVCLi7

Comment: I basically think I should find a way to match the timescale of 600 for the video with the timescale of audio, which returns 44100 (the bitrate of the audio track I enter). Am I right?

Comment: If the video is played at a slower rate than that of the original video - then you should expect to do something with audio. However, if you play the audio at a slower rate, it won’t sound like anything understandable to the human ear. So, why would you want the audio to play at a slower rate? You might look into finding a way to playing the video at a faster rate to match that of the original audio. Technically, you can’t move the audio. Making it go faster sounds like a robot, making it go slower sounds like mumble jumble.

Comment: What I did to compensate for the lag in video processing is to process only the images in a timeframe that allow the audio to play the images where the audio and images match timewise

Comment: So basically, what you are saying is, I need to manipulate the MTKView to only render an image every, let’s say, 50 ms, so the image is always “ready” to use and there would be no lag on the processing side?

Comment: Correct. So let’s say you play a video. You don’t wait for the next image. You calculate EXACTLY how long it took to process the image. Add that “lag” to the current time of the frame you just calculated. The next frame would be the time of the current frame plus the lag. But the audio plays smoothly as if nothing is happening. However, this assumes that the audio starts at the same time as the video player. On another note - my MTKView has gotten as slow as 15-25 fps. While this seems slow - real time video processing is hard. You have to compensate somewhere.

Comment: For example. You start on frame 0/600 seconds/preferredTimeScale. Then it takes 0.1 secs to process. Display this new filtered image. Next image would be 0 + 0.1 = 60/600. Let’s say that is 0.45 secs. 0.1 + 0.45 = 0.55 = 330/600z then 0.12. So, 0.55 + 0.12 = 0.67 = 402/600. And so on. All this, while your audio is playing smooth.

Comment: Hopefullly it is somewhere in the ballpark of 25/600 time/timescale or lower. That is a 24 fps rate and is still decent viewing rate.

Comment: Do you think other applications, for example Instagram, do it like this? I am creating something similar to their “add video” feature. Just open the app, hit the + button, choose Video, record a video and start editing and okaying with brightness etc. No delays.

Comment: How would I go about this, by the way? How can I control the frame rate of my MTKView? Can I somehow define this, or should I perform some sort of check in the rendering pipeline? Maybe you can add an answer, and if I manage to get it up and running (or even if the sync improves just a bit), I can award that bounty to you.

Comment: Sure! Let me get that to you shortly

Comment: Tbh - not a clue how IG or other image processing apps do  it. I do know that I had a similar problem and this is how I solved it.

Comment: I apologize. I had surgery. I should be able to post an answer within the next 24 hrs

Comment: I do have a question - Are you applying the effects AFTER you take the original video then displaying to the `MTKView`with the desired effects, or are you recording the original video WITH the effects attached, then displaying the final video to the user?

Comment: What you mentioned first. So you record a video - plain and simple, straight out of camera, no visual effects whatsoever. This recording is then exported to the temporary folder as mo4 file (with the bitrate of 6000000 and sample rate for audio of 441000 mentioned above). This mp4 file is then loaded and renders through the MTKView, upon which effects can now be added. By the way, I wish you a quick recovery. Hope nothing too bad and hope all is well.

Comment: All is fine. Minor stuff to fix a previous complicated surgery. No biggie. Thanks tho! On another note, I had originally thought this was taking the route 2. So, a few more questions. I actually needed both 1 and 2 for what I was doing. For route 1, however, the best approach I did was to recreate a new video entirely that already had the pre-rendered effects. So, the user would select it, and then you'd create an entirely new video with the desired effects. Depending on your effects, this could actually be relatively quick.

Comment: If you wanted something more like an overlay - you could potentially add an overlay on top of the video to create a "disguise" so that to the user it looked like it was meshed into 1, but realistically, the overlay is there to indicate to the user what it would look like. But, once the user presses "Done", you'd then create a "final" video with the ACTUAL filter presented with the video.

Comment: Ideally, the processing time for the filtering would be negligent but it isn't. So your options come down to creating a new video for the user or creating a "fake" video by creating some sort of overlay to the user and presenting that overlay on top of the video. Kind of like shining a light at a purple piece of paper. The light now appears purple but it really isn't. In both options, the original video could be placed with the original audio and the effects would either be 1) intertwined or 2) overlayed until the desired effect is chosen

Comment: Good to hear. Hmm, I can’t really add separate videos as my users can select different effects, like LUT (lookups), brightness, contrast, vibrance and then they can use a slider to choose the value they want (represented in %, so 0-100). I have not thought about an overlay yet, tho. How could that work for, let’s say, LUTs or vibrance, as I need the image data to process correctly? Can’t I render the MTKView at a slower pace and make sure it matches my audio? So the video becomes a bit “choppier”, but if I’m lucky it won’t be visible if it’s above 24 fps?

Comment: Well you can't render the video slower since your audio and video would render the same from initial video. What you could do, is remove certain frames so that you render less and can keep up the same pace to that of your audio. The problem is, you'd have to know exactly how long each render would be, for the route you are going. If you rendering took 60/600 frames per second, you'd know exactly that you'd want 10 fps to keep up with your audio.

Comment: Ah. And this process varies depending on the image (the data of the frame of the video, eg a pure black screen would render faster than a video with lots of different colors and details, I think) as well as what filter is chosen (LUTs would be more intensive than brightness, I guess). What if I change my bitrate to 2400000 instead of 600000? (Is this 24 fps and 60 fps or am I completely wrong here?) Or would this not impact the rendering time at all and actually change nothing?

Comment: Erm, tbh, not sure what the audio bitrate means hahaha. I try not to fidget with audio ever and only manipulate the video. Thing is, you don't know what video frames you need because you are unsure of the next frame.

Comment: I see. Completely understand that, too. It’s quite a mess. I’m now also thinking about pausing the MTKView until the processing is done. For example, when a filter is chosen, the MTKView.isPaused is set to true, and when the processing is done, we should need to get notified to continue drawing in the MTKView. Could this be a possible route towards a solution? [just thinking out loud right now, no idea how realistic this scenario would/could be]

Comment: Isn’t that the same thing as my answer below - recreating the entire video with the new processed video with the desired filtering?

Comment: Another solution - you could assume that your processing would never reduce you below 24 fps. (I’m not entirely sure on the validity of this but something to potentially test) and if so, you could just grab frames at 24 fps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I custom the BBMetalVideoSource as follow then it worked:

1. Create a delegate in BBMetalVideoSource to get the current time of the audio player with which we want to sync
2. In func `private func processAsset(progress:, completion:)`, I replace this block of code `if useVideoRate { //... }` by:

   ```
   if useVideoRate {
       if let playerTime = delegate.getAudioPlayerCurrentTime() {
           let diff = CMTimeGetSeconds(sampleFrameTime) - playerTime
           if diff > 0.0 {
               sleepTime = diff
               if sleepTime > 1.0 {
                   sleepTime = 0.0
               }
               usleep(UInt32(1000000 * sleepTime))
           } else {
               sleepTime = 0
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This code help us resolve both problems: 1. No audio when preview video effect, and 2. Sync audio with video.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 1. No audio when preview video effect? Does this mean the audio stops when an effect is applied, because I want to keep the audio running, but in sync.

Comment: @PennyWise The video example of BBMetalImage has two problem: 1. No audio 2. If we you AVPlayer to play audio to resolve problem 1 then the audio out of sync. And I just want to say that the code above resolves problem 2 then of course including problem 1

Comment: What is getAudioPlayerCurrentTime() or where does it come from? I understand it has to be set up, but how should I go about it? Return AVPlayer.currentItem?.currentTime?

Comment: I get a bunch of errors, probably because I parse the time in a wrong way. Any hints towards getAudioPlayerCurrentTime()?

Comment: Dude. Had to change a couple of things but basically this did the trick. My video and audio are synced as far as I can test right now. I am forever grateful, thank you so much. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your circumstances, you seem to need to try 1 of 2 things:

**1)** Try and apply some sort of overlay that has the desired effect for your video. I could attempt something like this, but I have personally not done this.

**2)** This takes a little more time beforehand - in the sense that the program would have to take a few moments (depending on your filtering, time varies), to recreate a new video with the desired effects. You can try this out and see if it works for you.

I have made my own VideoCreator using some sourcecode from SO from somewhere.

```
//Recreates a new video with applied filter
    public static func createFilteredVideo(asset: AVAsset, completionHandler: @escaping (_ asset: AVAsset) -> Void) {
        let url = (asset as? AVURLAsset)!.url
        let snapshot = url.videoSnapshot()
        guard let image = snapshot else { return }
        let fps = Int32(asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0].nominalFrameRate)
        let writer = VideoCreator(fps: Int32(fps), width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height, audioSettings: nil)

        let timeScale = asset.duration.timescale
        let timeValue = asset.duration.value
        let frameTime = 1/Double(fps) * Double(timeScale)
        let numberOfImages = Int(Double(timeValue)/Double(frameTime))
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.queue.queue", qos: .utility)
        let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset) { (request) in
            let source = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent()
            //This is where you create your filter and get your filtered result. 
            //Here is an example
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask")
            filter!.setValue(maskImage, forKey: "inputMaskImage")
            filter!.setValue(regCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")
            let filteredImage = filter!.outputImage.clamped(to: source.extent)
            request.finish(with: filteredImage, context: nil)
        }

        var i = 0
        getAudioFromURL(url: url) { (buffer) in
            writer.addAudio(audio: buffer, time: .zero)
            i == 0 ? writer.startCreatingVideo(initialBuffer: buffer, completion: {}) : nil
            i += 1
        }

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for i in 0..<numberOfImages {
            group.enter()
            autoreleasepool {
                let time = CMTime(seconds: Double(Double(i) * frameTime / Double(timeScale)), preferredTimescale: timeScale)
                let image = url.videoSnapshot(time: time, composition: composition)
                queue.async {

                    writer.addImageAndAudio(image: image!, audio: nil, time: time.seconds)
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: queue) {
            writer.finishWriting()
            let url = writer.getURL()

            //Now create exporter to add audio then do completion handler
            completionHandler(AVAsset(url: url))

        }
    }

    static func getAudioFromURL(url: URL, completionHandlerPerBuffer: @escaping ((_ buffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> Void)) {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: NSNumber(value: true as Bool)])

        guard let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load AVAssetTrack")
        }


        guard let reader = try? AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
            else {
                fatalError("Couldn't initialize the AVAssetReader")
        }
        reader.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)

        let outputSettingsDict: [String : Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false
        ]
        let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: assetTrack,
                                                    outputSettings: outputSettingsDict)
        readerOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
        reader.add(readerOutput)

        while reader.status == .reading {
            guard let readSampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() else { break }
            completionHandlerPerBuffer(readSampleBuffer)

        }
    }

extension URL {
    func videoSnapshot(time:CMTime? = nil, composition:AVVideoComposition? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: self)
        let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
        generator.videoComposition = composition

        let timestamp = time == nil ? CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60) : time

        do {
            let imageRef = try generator.copyCGImage(at: timestamp!, actualTime: nil)
            return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the VideoCreator

```
//
//  VideoCreator.swift
//  AKPickerView-Swift
//
//  Created by Impression7vx on 7/16/19.
//

import UIKit

import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import Photos

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public class VideoCreator: NSObject {

    private var settings:RenderSettings!
    private var imageAnimator:ImageAnimator!

    public override init() {
        self.settings = RenderSettings()
        self.imageAnimator = ImageAnimator(renderSettings: self.settings)
    }

    public convenience init(fps: Int32, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, audioSettings: [String:Any]?) {
        self.init()
        self.settings = RenderSettings(fps: fps, width: width, height: height)
        self.imageAnimator = ImageAnimator(renderSettings: self.settings, audioSettings: audioSettings)
    }

    public convenience init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
        self.settings = RenderSettings(width: width, height: height)
        self.imageAnimator = ImageAnimator(renderSettings: self.settings)
    }

    func startCreatingVideo(initialBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        self.imageAnimator.render(initialBuffer: initialBuffer) {
            completion()
        }
    }

    func finishWriting() {
        self.imageAnimator.isDone = true
    }

    func addImageAndAudio(image:UIImage, audio:CMSampleBuffer?, time:CFAbsoluteTime) {
        self.imageAnimator.addImageAndAudio(image: image, audio: audio, time: time)
    }

    func getURL() -> URL {
        return settings!.outputURL
    }

    func addAudio(audio: CMSampleBuffer, time: CMTime) {
        self.imageAnimator.videoWriter.addAudio(buffer: audio, time: time)
    }
}


@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public struct RenderSettings {

    var width: CGFloat = 1280
    var height: CGFloat = 720
    var fps: Int32 = 2   // 2 frames per second
    var avCodecKey = AVVideoCodecType.h264
    var videoFilename = "video"
    var videoFilenameExt = "mov"

    init() { }

    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }

    init(fps: Int32) {
        self.fps = fps
    }

    init(fps: Int32, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.fps = fps
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }

    var size: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    var outputURL: URL {
        // Use the CachesDirectory so the rendered video file sticks around as long as we need it to.
        // Using the CachesDirectory ensures the file won't be included in a backup of the app.
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let tmpDirURL = try? fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true) {
            return tmpDirURL.appendingPathComponent(videoFilename).appendingPathExtension(videoFilenameExt)
        }
        fatalError("URLForDirectory() failed")
    }
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public class ImageAnimator {

    // Apple suggests a timescale of 600 because it's a multiple of standard video rates 24, 25, 30, 60 fps etc.
    static let kTimescale: Int32 = 600

    let settings: RenderSettings
    let videoWriter: VideoWriter
    var imagesAndAudio:SynchronizedArray<(UIImage, CMSampleBuffer?, CFAbsoluteTime)> = SynchronizedArray<(UIImage, CMSampleBuffer?, CFAbsoluteTime)>()
    var isDone:Bool = false
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    var frameNum = 0

    class func removeFileAtURL(fileURL: URL) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
        }
        catch _ as NSError {
            // Assume file doesn't exist.
        }
    }

    init(renderSettings: RenderSettings, audioSettings:[String:Any]? = nil) {
        settings = renderSettings
        videoWriter = VideoWriter(renderSettings: settings, audioSettings: audioSettings)
    }

    func addImageAndAudio(image: UIImage, audio: CMSampleBuffer?, time:CFAbsoluteTime) {
        self.imagesAndAudio.append((image, audio, time))
//        print("Adding to array -- \(self.imagesAndAudio.count)")
    }

    func render(initialBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, completion: @escaping ()->Void) {

        // The VideoWriter will fail if a file exists at the URL, so clear it out first.
        ImageAnimator.removeFileAtURL(fileURL: settings.outputURL)

        videoWriter.start(initialBuffer: initialBuffer)
        videoWriter.render(appendPixelBuffers: appendPixelBuffers) {
            //ImageAnimator.saveToLibrary(self.settings.outputURL)
            completion()
        }

    }

    // This is the callback function for VideoWriter.render()
    func appendPixelBuffers(writer: VideoWriter) -> Bool {

        //Don't stop while images are NOT empty
        while !imagesAndAudio.isEmpty || !isDone {

            if(!imagesAndAudio.isEmpty) {
                let date = Date()

                if writer.isReadyForVideoData == false {
                    // Inform writer we have more buffers to write.
//                    print("Writer is not ready for more data")
                    return false
                }

                autoreleasepool {
                    //This should help but truly doesn't suffice - still need a mutex/lock
                    if(!imagesAndAudio.isEmpty) {
                        semaphore.wait() // requesting resource
                        let imageAndAudio = imagesAndAudio.first()!
                        let image = imageAndAudio.0
//                        let audio = imageAndAudio.1
                        let time = imageAndAudio.2
                        self.imagesAndAudio.removeAtIndex(index: 0)
                        semaphore.signal() // releasing resource
                        let presentationTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 600)

//                        if(audio != nil) { videoWriter.addAudio(buffer: audio!) }
                        let success = videoWriter.addImage(image: image, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                        if success == false {
                            fatalError("addImage() failed")
                        }
                        else {
//                            print("Added image @ frame \(frameNum) with presTime: \(presentationTime)")
                        }

                        frameNum += 1
                        let final = Date()
                        let timeDiff = final.timeIntervalSince(date)
//                        print("Time: \(timeDiff)")
                    }
                    else {
//                        print("Images was empty")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print("Done writing")
        // Inform writer all buffers have been written.
        return true
    }

}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public class VideoWriter {

    let renderSettings: RenderSettings
    var audioSettings: [String:Any]?
    var videoWriter: AVAssetWriter!
    var videoWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    var pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor!
    var audioWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    static var ci:Int = 0
    var initialTime:CMTime!

    var isReadyForVideoData: Bool {
        return (videoWriterInput == nil ? false : videoWriterInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData )
    }

    var isReadyForAudioData: Bool {
        return (audioWriterInput == nil ? false : audioWriterInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData)
    }

    class func pixelBufferFromImage(image: UIImage, pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool, size: CGSize, alpha:CGImageAlphaInfo) -> CVPixelBuffer? {

        var pixelBufferOut: CVPixelBuffer?

        let status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBufferOut)
        if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
            fatalError("CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer() failed")
        }

        let pixelBuffer = pixelBufferOut!

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])

        let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                                bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: alpha.rawValue)

        context!.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        let horizontalRatio = size.width / image.size.width
        let verticalRatio = size.height / image.size.height
        //aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
        let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit

        let newSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width * aspectRatio, height: image.size.height * aspectRatio)

        let x = newSize.width < size.width ? (size.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
        let y = newSize.height < size.height ? (size.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0

        let cgImage = image.cgImage != nil ? image.cgImage! : image.ciImage!.convertCIImageToCGImage()

        context!.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])
        return pixelBuffer
    }

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    init(renderSettings: RenderSettings, audioSettings:[String:Any]? = nil) {
        self.renderSettings = renderSettings
        self.audioSettings = audioSettings
    }

    func start(initialBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?) {

        let avOutputSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: renderSettings.avCodecKey as AnyObject,
            AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.width)),
            AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.height))
        ]

        let avAudioSettings = audioSettings

        func createPixelBufferAdaptor() {
            let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [
                kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
                kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.width)),
                kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.height))
            ]
            pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
                                                                      sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)
        }

        func createAssetWriter(outputURL: URL) -> AVAssetWriter {
            guard let assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: AVFileType.mov) else {
                fatalError("AVAssetWriter() failed")
            }

            guard assetWriter.canApply(outputSettings: avOutputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaType.video) else {
                fatalError("canApplyOutputSettings() failed")
            }

            return assetWriter
        }

        videoWriter = createAssetWriter(outputURL: renderSettings.outputURL)
        videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: avOutputSettings)
//        if(audioSettings != nil) {
        audioWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: nil)
        audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
//        }

        if videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
            videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)
        }
        else {
            fatalError("canAddInput() returned false")
        }

//        if(audioSettings != nil) {
            if videoWriter.canAdd(audioWriterInput) {
                videoWriter.add(audioWriterInput)
            }
            else {
                fatalError("canAddInput() returned false")
            }
//        }

        // The pixel buffer adaptor must be created before we start writing.
        createPixelBufferAdaptor()

        if videoWriter.startWriting() == false {
            fatalError("startWriting() failed")
        }


        self.initialTime = initialBuffer != nil ? CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(initialBuffer!) : CMTime.zero
        videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: self.initialTime)

        precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil, "nil pixelBufferPool")
    }

    func render(appendPixelBuffers: @escaping (VideoWriter)->Bool, completion: @escaping ()->Void) {

        precondition(videoWriter != nil, "Call start() to initialze the writer")

        let queue = DispatchQueue(__label: "mediaInputQueue", attr: nil)
        videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: queue) {
            let isFinished = appendPixelBuffers(self)
            if isFinished {
                self.videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                self.videoWriter.finishWriting() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Done Creating Video")
                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Fall through. The closure will be called again when the writer is ready.
            }
        }
    }

    func addAudio(buffer: CMSampleBuffer, time: CMTime) {
        if(isReadyForAudioData) {
            print("Writing audio \(VideoWriter.ci) of a time of \(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buffer))")
            let duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(buffer)
            let offsetBuffer = CMSampleBuffer.createSampleBuffer(fromSampleBuffer: buffer, withTimeOffset: time, duration: duration)
            if(offsetBuffer != nil) {
                print("Added audio")
                self.audioWriterInput.append(offsetBuffer!)
            }
            else {
                print("Not adding audio")
            }
        }

        VideoWriter.ci += 1
    }

    func addImage(image: UIImage, withPresentationTime presentationTime: CMTime) -> Bool {

        precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor != nil, "Call start() to initialze the writer")
        //1
        let pixelBuffer = VideoWriter.pixelBufferFromImage(image: image, pixelBufferPool: pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, size: renderSettings.size, alpha: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst)!

        return pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime + self.initialTime)
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s crazy. I’ll need some time to go over this comprehensive answer, but I’m sure I’ll learn a lot. Will look into it in depth tomorrow night or Saturday morning. Thank you so much for all the help and suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking a little further into this - and while I could have updated my answer, I'd rather open this tangent in a new area to separate these ideas. Apple states that we can use an `AVVideoComposition` to "To use the created video composition for playback, create an AVPlayerItem object from the same asset used as the composition’s source, then assign the composition to the player item’s videoComposition property. To export the composition to a new movie file, create an AVAssetExportSession object from the same source asset, then assign the composition to the export session’s videoComposition property.".

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronousciimagefilteringrequest

So, what you COULD try is using the AVPlayer for the ORIGINAL URL. Then try applying your filter.

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in

    // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
    let source = request.sourceImage.imageByClampingToExtent()
    filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
    filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
    let output = filter.outputImage!.imageByCroppingToRect(request.sourceImage.extent)

    // Provide the filter output to the composition
    request.finishWithImage(output, context: nil)
})

let asset = AVAsset(url: originalURL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
item.videoComposition = composition
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```

I'm sure you know what to do from here. This may allow you to do a "Real-time" of your filtering. What I could see as a potential issue is that this runs into the same issues as your original thing, whereas it still takes a set time to run each frame and leading to a delay between audio and video. However, this may not happen. If you do get this working, once the user selects their filter, you can use `AVAssetExportSession` to export the specific `videoComposition`.

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronousciimagefilteringrequest) if you need help!

Comment: Haven't really figured it out yet, but accepted your answer as you have given me a lot of insight so far.

Comment: Let me know if I can help further

Comment: Just found a couple more interesting values. This is print output from a 14 second video I recorded and played back in my app through the MTKView (using a videoSource) and the audio through an AVPlayer: https://pastebin.com/4c1EwgyM - notice how the audio starts with a delay. This, I can probably fix. Anything else we can learn from that output?

Comment: What I understand is, when I have a value in the currentTime() of the audioPlayer of 230160165, and the timescale is 1000000000, it means the audio is at 0.230160165 seconds (230160165 / 1000000000), right? In that same moment, the lastSampleFrameRate is at value 180 with a timescale of 600, which is at 0.3 seconds (180 / 600). This also makes sense: the audio always ends a little before the video (I can record up to 15 seconds in my app). I feel like I need to sync those timescales together and the problem should be resolved?

Comment: But the problem isn’t linear. Notice the “lag” between rhe audio and video increaase for each frame. It’s not like once you align 1 frame, the rest will align. It’s bring played at a different rate, because the time to process the filter id variable. Try this - play the video without any filtering. It should work. If it doesn’t, then this has other issues

Comment: That’s the funny thing. When I start the playback, there are no filters applied (yet). Filters arz chosen by the user, and even when there are none and the raw video renders through the MTKView, there is a delay. I even think my output above was from raw video and audio without filters applied.

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a delay issue based off of filtering then. A whole new issue is there :P

Comment: I just think it has to do with the MTKView which renders at a different rate (I don’t know why) as the AVPlayer.

Comment: Ooooo. You are right. You can set the fps. Totally forgot. View.preferredFramesPerSecond. You can get the assets by getting rhe assets video track’s nominal rate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666884/ios-avplayer-get-fps and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/1536027-preferredframespersecond

Comment: So in essence, you can set the fps of the mtkview to that of the asset you are using. This should give you a baseline prior to all the filtering issues you wil experience.

Comment: Read the documentation, however, it only applies it if it can

Comment: Haven’t been able to implement the fps stuff due to work. However, if it doesn’t work, I’ll probably leave it how it is now: audio and video are a second out of sync, and audio finishes a bit sooner than video, but when exporting the video it’s fine. That’s the most essential part. Have spent hours already trying to fix it and it’s only improved slightly as to where I started in the first place. Feel like this is an active issue that hasn’t been adressed very much